# Dynamic S3 Link for downloading or viewing a PDF

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am storing some customer PDFs in S3 for multiple parties to either view in the browser or download. The trouble is I can only get a single file in S3 to either always download or always view in the browser.

I could just upload the same file twice with each having its own `ContentDisposition`, but that seems wasteful when ideally it could be as simple as adding something like `?ContentDisposition=inline` to the public bucket URL.

**My Question:** How can dynamically set a `ContentDisposition` for a single S3 file?

For context, my current code looks something like this:

```php
$s3_object = array(
  'ContentDisposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', addslashes($basename)),
  'ACL'                => 'public-read',
  'ContentType'        => 'pdf',
  'StorageClass'       => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
  'Bucket'             => 'sample',
  'Key'                => static::build_file_path($path, $filename, $extension),
  'Body'               => $binary_content,
);

$result = $s3_client->putObject($s3_object);
```

---

Also, I did try to search for this elsewhere in SO, but most people seem to just be looking for one or the other, so I didn't find any SO answers that showed how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stumbling across the definitive answer for this today (over a month later) while looking at other S3 documentation. Going to the [GetObject docs for the S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) and under the section labeled "Overriding Response Header Values" we find the following:

> Note: You must sign the request, either using an Authorization header or a presigned URL, when using these parameters. They cannot be used with an unsigned (anonymous) request.
>
> - response-content-language
> - response-expires
> - response-cache-control
> - response-content-disposition
> - response-content-encoding

**This answer's how to dynamically change any S3 object's content-disposition in the URL.** However, at least for me, this is an imperfect solution because my intended use case was to store the URL for years as part of an invoicing archive, but signed URLs are only valid for a maximum of 1 week.

I could technically also try to find a way to make the Authorization header work for me or just query the S3 API to get a new signed URL every time I want to link to it, but that has other security, performance, and ROI implications for me that make it not worth it.